# What kind of camera do I need to capture deep space images?

Tags: astrophotography, camera-recommendation, stars, milky-way

By deep space image, I mean below kind. In the background it is space dust, I think.
Is it dependent on camera or location? If on camera, what kind of cameras are capable to capture this kind of images?

[image]

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4298/whats-the-best-technique-and-kit-for-taking-a-picture-of-the-milky-way-in-a-nea/14602#14602

Comment: These are quite difficult to shot. (I believe that's the milky way) This is more about a tripod and post processing then it is about the camera. (The tripod must be capable of compensating for earth's rotation) There is also good deal of post processing involved to take out the noise inherent in long exposures like these. It looks like there is also some sort of light painting involved here to illuminate the structure.

Comment: Any camera that lets you use bulb shutter speed settings. DSLR will let you do that, but you can buy a cheap bridge as well. It's all a matter of post-processing actually. Or maybe use some ultra ultra expensive camera as stated in an answer.

Comment: This appears to be the source of the image (CC-BY licensed by     Bala Sivakumar): http://www.flickr.com/photos/bala_/4766723931/ He indicates that it is not a stacked image.

Comment: That's not "space dust", by the way. It's stars!

Comment: It's both. There is still a lot of interstellar dust near the center of the galaxy.

Comment: Amateur astronomers will often use a "tripod" (telescope mount) with a built-in clock mechanism that rotates the camera (telescope) to allow for long (several minute) exposures without star trails.  It tracks the stars during their apparent motion through the sky.  Of course the mount has to be correctly aligned first.  The images are typically composed of two separate parts: one with a short exposure to capture the foreground (trees, buildings) and one with a long exposure (using tracking) to capture the stars.

Comment: That's not "deep space" by any means :p To take deep space images you need a camera mounted in a satellite (like the Hubble) xD

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I found this page while checking my stats on Flickr. (I'm the photographer that shot this photo)
I thought I'd respond with details of how I created this image since I see multiple theories here.

First - this is not a stacked exposure. The entire image is a single exposure (30 secs). I used a Nikon D700 DSLR at ISO 3200 to capture this image (at ~20mm/f2.8).

Also, the background is indeed the Milky way as some of the answers mention. (This was shot when the moon was just rising - so the skies were still dark)

There is no 'digital trickery' involved at all (unless you count RAW processing as 'digital trickery'). As rfusca mentions, I merely light-painted the foreground with a flashlight for illumination.

The D700 is an example of a camera that has very low noise at high ISO - thus, the image works even at full-resolution (12.1 MP). There are ways to achieve even lower noise (downsampling, [dark-frame subtraction](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-frame-subtraction) etc..), but I didn't do any of that for this image.

The most important part of getting an image like this is to find an area with dark skies.
(More images with Milky way can be found here: http://www.flickr.com/photos/bala_/tags/nightsky/)

If anyone has additional questions, I'm happy to answer them!

Comment: Woohoo!  Score one for me! hehehe.  Great shot by the way, love it.

Comment: Welcome to PhotoSE, Bala! Many thanks for taking the time to answer this question! Its much appreciated. :)

Comment: @Bala: thanks for getting in the loop. Can we see the milkyway with naked eyes on a dark, clear night? I live in New Zealand (and India) and I have never seen space dust. Am I in the wrong locations and missing it all?

Comment: @ReddySR: Absolutely! You can see the Milky Way *very* clearly with naked eyes. The trick is to get away from big cities and light pollution - from what I've read rural NZ is ideal for this!

You're also very fortunate living in the Southern Hemisphere since you can see more of the 'good parts' of the Milky way than us in the Northern Hemisphere (winter months are the best time for you - summer months for us).

For more samples of Milky way shots, see http://www.flickr.com/photos/bala_/sets/72157628001569892/detail/ and http://www.wanderingmonkphoto.com/night

Comment: Sounds very exciting. Do you think Canon 7D can do this job? It support ISO 100 - 6400 but read http://snapsort.com/compare/Canon_EOS_5D_Mark_II-vs-Canon_EOS_7D 7D does not win in low light scenes.

Comment: Yes - the Canon 7D can definitely do it (images might be noisy, but you can clean up with post-processing and dark-frame subtraction). Note that you will need a fast lens (something like the 24mm/f1.4) for best results. For more information on shooting static star shots, I found this very helpful: http://www.texbrick.com/photo/notes/starshots.pdf

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, a lot of images like the one you show here are digitally altered and it is difficult to get comparable results. The image above shows the Milky Way, looking approximately at its center, which appears to us to be in the constellation of Sagittarius.

To get such a detailed view of the comparatively dark nebulous structures, however, you need to use really long exposure times. Unfortunately, because of the stars' apparent rotation, exposures above approximately 25 seconds (for wide angle lenses; the smaller your lens angle, the shorter the time) begin to show [star trails](http://www.andromedaforum.de/pg/galleries/image/82/index.php). So I doubt that the image you show was really created as one exposure. If so, the photographer must have used an extremely low-noise semsor with exceptionally high sensitivity.

The linked "star trail" image (which shows the telescope I work for, by the way) used a technique called "stacking". To create it, 70 1-minute-exposures were added together. This is a common method that allows you to get very good images using a normal DSLR and an external timer/trigger.

If you stack the images so that the star "pinpoints" are on top of each other, you will get a detailed skyscape with blurred foreground. This is what I suppose was done in your example image: The sky was images with a series of exposures, stacked together for greater sensitivity, and the foreground has likely been added afterwards.

Of course, instead of doing that much digital manipulation, you can also follow the traditional route and mount your (D)SLR on a tracking mount. A good description with sample images that show what to expect from real-world exposures is given on the "[bedfordnights](https://web.archive.org/web/20091028024449/http://www.geocities.com/bedfordnights/widefieldtutorial.html)" Geocities page (link to archived copy at Internet Archive).

**Edit:** I forgot to address your question regarding location. Yes, it depends on the location: For one thing, the center of the milky way (which is its brightest area) gets higher above the horizon when you move from the poles to the equator. But most importantly, images of the quality you show above are only possible from the darkest locations on the planet (which sounds exotic and adventurous, but essentially means "anywhere where there are no human settlements causing light pollution in about 200 km radius").

Comment: You're likely right that this is probably stacked and the foreground digitally added, but I've seen similar shots that weren't.  With a really low noise camera and a really, really dark sky, you can get these kinds of pictures in shot shot *if* they're scaled down to size like this.

Comment: @jstarek: Bedfordnights was great link, for I came to know what I was looking for is astrophotography and cheapest means to get nice quality images :) Thanks!

Comment: @rfusca: What do you mean by shot shot? Is there any link for your procedure to easier astrophotography?

Comment: no, you can't get this kind of shot without digital trickery. Either the background will be too dark or the foreground blown out, and/or you get star trails which would have even at this scale the stars show up as fuzzy blurs rather than point sources.

Comment: @jwenting - at smaller sizes, you really really can.  The buildings can be illuminated with light painting is how I saw it done.   I'm not saying that I think this particular one was done that way, but you honestly can.

Comment: @jwenting See Sullivan's photograph in Matt Grum's answer: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18513/how-does-peter-lik-manage-to-capture-the-stars-in-such-detail-in-the-following-p As rfusca says, the foreground can be illuminated with light painting or flash. The lens used in this question's photo appears to be a wider angle than Sullivan used and so can tolerate even longer exposure without trailing.

Comment: Today, on universetoday.com, there was a link to an image that is probably among the very best possible without digital alterations: http://www.flickr.com/photos/67234957@N06/6308631822/in/set-72157627806219336 clearly shows the milky way's central structures and was taken with a Canon 550d at 25 second exposure at 17mm, f3.5, ISO 3200. The electricity pole (lower right in the image) hints that the photographer was not too far in the wilderness. Note the "trick" with the hilly horizon: This removes a lot of possible light pollution from your immediate zenith view.

Comment: @rfusca yes, flash was clearly used on the foreground. See the dropoff in illumination towards the sides of the structure. Which makes it even more suspicious, as the background is far too bright in comparison with the foreground. Residual light should have caused more illumination of the foreground than is apparent here, not less, over the duration of the exposure.

Comment: @jwenting - see the larger image coneslayer indicated above and the author claiming its not stacked.  You can see the trailing clearer on the larger image too.

Comment: Look closely at that image and you see it's either stacked or the foreground has been selected in PS and adjusted separately from the starscape. There's a clear outline, especially on the upper edge of the stones.

Comment: geocities (lol) lik is dead

Comment: @luchonacho Thanks for the heads-up. I changed the link in the answer to point to the Internet Archive's copy of the page. BTW, instead of alerting people via a comment, you can edit the question yourself.