# Which is better for Astrophotography when we compare Canon 70D and Canon 760D

Tags: canon, astrophotography, canon-70d

I have Canon 1200D and now I am more interested towards astrophotography.
I am confused between which one to go for. Canon 70D or Canon 760D.

Lens I hold: 
18-55mm, 50mm 1.8 STM, 55-250mm IS II

Please advise.

Comment: What do you find about your current equipment is holding back your astrophotography?

Comment: Canon 1200D is Basic entry level camera. Thus 18 Mega Pixel Images sensor is producing lot of noise in high ISO from 1600-3200 in LOW light specially when we go for astrophotography  where you don't actually have enough light.

Comment: Because of High ISO and Noise images I clicked are not appropriate and very noisy.

Comment: The 70D and 760D collect the same amount of light as the 1200D when using the same lenses. All three will be noisy, and fairly close in terms of exactly how noisy.

Comment: There are many techniques to reduce noise in astrophotography that are far more effective than buying a new camera with only a very marginal difference in the SNR.d

Comment: @Michael Clark . Thanks for the reply. 
Can you please guide me with those techniques.

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrophotography

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/82850/how-do-star-trackers-work-to-take-a-photo-for-5-minutes-without-blur-and-are-th

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-stacking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither.

Just as the critical measure for most astronomical telescopes is how much light they can collect from each distant point source, the critical measure for a camera used in astrophotography is how much light from each distant point source they can collect. Just as telescopes with larger diameter objectives collect more light that those with smaller diameter objectives, larger imaging sensors collect more light from the same field of view than smaller imaging sensors do.

Both the 70D and the 760D have the same size sensor, so neither has an advantage there. I guess if both perform equally for the intended purpose then one might argue that the lower priced option is "better", but in terms of the results they would only be equal.

Comment: But as per my experience till now, there will definitely be difference in 18, 20.2 and 24 MP sensors in Low Light.

Comment: Conventional wisdom says the lower resolution sensor will show *less* noise. In practice newer technology often overcomes this. But the differences are still very small when compared to cameras of the same technological generation with larger sensors, where the differences are far greater.

Comment: @mohit And what is your 'experience ' ? Are you a photography expert ? Are you a better photographer than Michael Clark ? Do you think more megapixels help in low light ? It is usually the opposite.

Comment: @Janas: No my friend rather no one is better photographer. Everyone learns day by day. There might be few clicks which could be marvelous than a click of a professional. It's matter of what, where, and when and a little more experience would add the title of "Best Photo" to the click.

as explained by him about the sensors and megapixel. I got that very much clear and yeah I went through lot of videos and science behind sensors and megapixel.
I appreciate you involvement. :)
Thank you.